# Python: create category based on values in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, label

Say I have two lists:

```
arrayA = np.array([3,4,1,2,5,6,8,6,3])
arrayB = np.array([4,2,5,6,1,3,6,5,3])
```

which basically represents a point in 2D.

I want to get a label list that looks like:

```
listLael = [type1,type2,type1,type2,...]
```

that have the same length as arrayA and arrayB and

```
type1 if arrayA value >= 5 and arrayB value >= 5
type2 if eith arrayA or arrayB value < 5
```

I know that I can go through both array and get it but is there are fast and convenient way of doing this with numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where((arrayA >= 5) & (arrayB >= 5), 'type1', 'type2')
array(['type2', 'type2', 'type2', 'type2', 'type2', 'type2', 'type1',
       'type1', 'type2'],
      dtype='|S5')
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted.